# (Flutter) How to listen changes in TextField automatically, without pressing "Done"?

Tags: dart, flutter

I Print input from TextField in a dialog (Both TextField and output are in AlertDialog). The output is updated only when I press 'Done' in the keyboard. If I don't press Done, it keeps showing me the old output.

**Here is my source code:**

```
Future<void> widePopUpCustom() async {
  return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Enter Number'),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ListBody(children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                  controller: customRun,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Number',
                  )),
              Text('${customRun.text}'),
            ])),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  child: Text('OK'), onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context))
            ]);
      });
}
```

I have declared controller too:

```
  final TextEditingController customRun = TextEditingController();
```

(Further Clarification) **This is my output which I want to update in real time while entering text in my TextField, without pressing done in keyboard**

```
 Text('${customRun.text}'),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For demo, you may look here. [Example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ejabu/flutter_text_field_listener/master/demo.gif)

### 1. Identify Text widget that needs rebuild

First we expect content inside this widget to be rebuild as user types.

```dart
Text('${customRun.text}'),
```

Unfortunately, this widget resides inside widePopUpCustom method as 
Alert Dialog children

```dart
void widePopUpCustom() async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Enter Number'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  controller: customRun,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Number',
                  ),
                ),
                Text('${customRun.text}'), // Needs to be re-rendered
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

in this case, we cannot trigger rebuild on `AlertDialog` widget including all of its childern, `ListBody`, `TextField` and `Text` widget.

### 2. Split `AlertDialog` and convert it to Stateful Widget

We consider moving `AlertDialog` into `AlertWrapper`, and define `AlertWrapper` as **Stateful Widget**. So later, we can trigger rebuild of `AlertWrapper` using this code :

```dart
setState((){})
```

We can conclude this step, as modifying `widePopUpCustom()` to this one :

```dart
Future<void> widePopUpCustom() async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertWrapper();
      },
    );
  }
```

> Before, AlertDialog will be considered as Stateless that won't be re-rendered unless we close the dialog.

### 3. Override Stateful Widget to attach listener

By using stateful widget, we can explore initState usage. In this case, we attach `addListener` to `customRun` TextController.

> Please notice changesOnField method. This method will be triggered each time user interacts with keyboard input

```dart
class AlertWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  const AlertWrapper({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AlertWrapperState createState() => _AlertWrapperState();
}

class _AlertWrapperState extends State<AlertWrapper> {
  final TextEditingController customRun = TextEditingController();

  changesOnField() { 
    print("Updated Text: ${customRun.text}");
    setState(() {}); // Will re-Trigger Build Method
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    customRun.addListener(changesOnField);
  }
}
```

changesOnField will trigger build method to be re-called, and then we can our value inside Text widget updated

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Enter Number'),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ListBody(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: customRun,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Number',
              ),
            ),
            Text('${customRun.text}'), // Finally re-rendered
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

### Full-working Repo

You may look to this repo. [Github](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_text_field_listener)

### More improvements

As [official docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes#complete-example) states, we need to dispose the listener to optimize the app.

later we can add this code

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
  customRun.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `onChanged(txt)` method for the textfield and it has to contain a `setState()` within in order for the text to refresh each time you type a character

```
Future<void> widePopUpCustom() async {
  return showDialog<void>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Enter Number'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
              controller: customRun,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Number',
              )),
              onChanged:(txt){
                 setState((){
                   customRun.text = txt;
                 }),    
                 },
          Text('${customRun.text}'),
        ])),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
              child: Text('OK'), onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context))
        ]);
  });
```

}

Comment: It's still not updating output in real time. It is only updating when I press 'Done' in keyboard.

Just a clarification:  Text('${customRun.text}'), is my output

Comment: i recomand you add a new String variable to store the inputs in and output it in the text view, i use it quite often and it works and update for each letter i add